# Get objectid of the uploaded image in parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

i'm trying to get the objectId of the image that i upload with PARSE Javascript.
With the following code im uploading successfuly the image to my parse app but also i'm trying to print out the object id of this uploaded image.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {



     Parse.initialize("appid", "jskey");

      function saveJobApp(objParseFile)
      {
         var jobApplication = new Parse.Object("magazia");              
         jobApplication.set("name", "Joe Smith");                       
         jobApplication.set("image", objParseFile);                     
         jobApplication.save(null,                                      
         {
            success: function(gameScore) {

              var photo = gameScore.get("image");
              var name = gameScore.get("name");
              var id = gameScore.get("objectId");
             $("#profileImg")[0].src = photo.url();
             $("#name")[0].innerHTML = name;
             $("#objID")[0].innerHTML = id;
            },
            error: function(gameScore, error) {

              alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
            }
         });
      }

      $('#profilePhotoFileUpload').bind("change", function(e) {
             var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
             var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
             var name = file.name; 
             var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

             parseFile.save().then
             (
               function() 
               {
                   saveJobApp(parseFile);
               }, 
               function(error) 
               {
                 alert("error");
               }
             );
      }); 

    });
    </script>
</head>    
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="profilePhotoFileUpload">
        <img id="profileImg"/>
        <p id="name"></p>
        <p id="objID"></p>
    </body>
```

So i get the image and the name properly but i dont get the objectId and it says undefined.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving Object documentation from javaScript parse object you can use the following code :

```
var id = gameScore.id;

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-retrieving-objects
```

as you can see here it says exactly what you have to do with the data that parse itself makes to your class, such as objectId or time created and time updated. hope it helps.

Comment: yes this printed out the objectId of the image! Thanks!